# What does uint8 function do?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, uint, imshow

I'm trying to show the negative of an image and as you know it has a very simple code.
This is the original image:
[image]
When I use the code:

```
Out = 255-img;
%Out = uint8(OutNeg);
imshow(Out);
```

The result will be:
[image]

But using the code:

```
OutNeg = 255-img;
Out = uint8(OutNeg);
imshow(Out);
```

Will make the right answer:
[image]
Now I am wondering

1 - what does the function uint8() does in fact?
2 - Do these codes make the same results? In fact what is the usage of uint8?

Code1:

```
img2 = uint8(img1);  
imshow(img2);
```

Code2:

```
imshow(img1,[0 255]);
```

3 - Do I need to normalize the image before showing it with the following code?

```
img2 = 255/(max(max(img1))-min(min(img1)))*(img1-min(min(img1)));
```

Or using uint8 or [0 255] does the same thing and no need to normalize??

4- what is the difference between normalizing, using uint8 and using [0 255]??????

**please consider transformations like Log and power-low in your answers.**

Comment: you know exactly what uint8 does if you read the documentation. what is the class of your original image? try `class(img)` and see

Comment: double! Because it's a .dat image and I have changed it to double while reading the image!

Answer (score 3):

From `help imshow`:

```
If your grayscale image is single or double, the default display range is
[0 1]. If your image's data range is much larger or smaller than the default
display range, you may need to experiment with setting the display range to
see features in the image that would not be visible using the default
display range. For all grayscale images having integer types, the default
display range is [intmin(class(I)) intmax(class(I))].
```

By making your data an 8-bit unsigned integer (`uint8`) array, the data is expected by `imshow` to be on `[0 255]`. RTM.

Comment: Well then @chappjc as you say, before showing the result I should normalize the image with the formula `img2 = 255/(max(max(img1))-min(min(img1)))*(img1-min(min(img1)));` in order to have all the result pixels in [0 255] range and then because the result is an image of class double, I should use `imshow(uint8(img2))` to show it. Right??  And also when I use `uint8', there's no need to say imshow(img2,[0 255])!!  Do you think my understanding is perfectly true or there are more things to be considered???

Comment: And one more question @chappjc! I searched the documentation for imshow in MATLABR2013B and couldn't find the paragraph that you've attached.  Could you please link the help page?  I sometimes wonder where should I search before asking questions and why I can't solve the problem before asking a question?

Comment: @sepideh Sorry for the very late response. This bit of documentation is only available when you type `help imshow` on the command line. It is unfortunate that some bits of documentation are only available this way. For example, `help punct` is a real gem.